# Range of absolute value function $g(x) = |4 - x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A function $g$ is defined as $g(x)=|4-x|$, find the range of $g$ if its domain is $-3\leq x \leq 6$.

My attempt:

I substitute $-3$ and $6$ into the function and I got $2$ and $7$. And the answer is between $0$ to $7$.

What should I do to get the correct answer ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I' suggest to you to write $g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
4-x,&x\leq4\\
x-4,&x\geq4
\end{array}\right.$ .

Comment: I think you meant to write "find the range of $g$ if its domain is $-3 \leq \color{red}{x} \leq 6$."

Comment: The absolute value function is not a monotonic function so you cannot tell the range by just looking at the endpoints. Consider another non-monotonic function $f(x)=x^2$ for  $-1\leq x\leq 1.$ We have $f(-1)=f(1)=1$ but the range is not $\{1\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with the graph of the absolute value function $f(x) = |x|$.  Since $|x|$ represents the distance of the number $x$ from $0$, 
$$|x| = \begin{cases}
x && \text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
-x && \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, its graph consists of the two rays $y = x, x \geq 0$ and $y = -x, x < 0$.  The common endpoint of these two rays is the vertex of the graph, which is located at the origin.

[image: absolute_value_function_graph]

Observe that $|x| = |-x|$ since the points $x$ and $-x$ are equidistant zero.  Hence, 
$$|4 - x| = |-(4 - x)| = |-4 + x| = |x - 4|$$
The graph of $y = |x - 4|$ is obtained from the graph of $f(x)$ by translating the graph of $f(x)$ by four units to the right.  You should be able to convince yourself of this by making a table of values for $y = |x|$ and $y = |x - 4|$.  Another way to see this is to write the piecewise definition @shn stated in the comments
$$|4 - x| = |x - 4| = \begin{cases}
x - 4 && \text{if $x \geq 4$}\\
4 - x && \text{if $x < 4$}
\end{cases}
$$ 
then graph the rays $y = x - 4, x \geq 4$ and $y = 4 -x, x < 4$.

[image: translated_absolute_value_graph]

Restricting the domain $y = |x - 4|$ to $[-3, 6]$ yields the graph of $g(x) = |x - 4|, -3 \leq x \leq 6$.

[image: graph_of_translated_absolute_value_graph_with_restricted_domain]

From its graph, we see that $g$ has minimum value $0$ at $x = 4$ (its vertex) and maximum value $7$ at $x = -3$.  Since the function is continuous, it assumes every value between $0$ and $7$ in the interval $[-3, 4]$ and, consequently, in the interval $[-3, 6]$.